# write a CSV file by column in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code and I need to writing by column, by example I need the output be like this:

```
columnA  columnB  columnC  columnD
Hello,1  World,2  Monty,3  Python,4
```

Not like this:

```
Hello,1
World,2
Monty,3
Python,4
```

Code:

```
list_1 = ["Hello", "World", "Monty", "Python"]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
file = open("columns.txt", "w")
writer = csv.writer(file)
for w in range(4):
iterate through integers 0-3
writer.writerow([list_1[w], list_2[w]])
file.close()
```

Comment: Don't mention it.

Comment: That's two spaces between rows, right? Can the string in column 1 also have spaces and how would you deal with them?

Comment: This is just for clarification, there is no need for spaces, I just want to write on the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lineterminator` option to redifine what `csv.writer` writes after each row. It doesn't have to be a newline - spaces work just as well. Using a couple of other features (`zip` to iterate the lists and `writerows` to get rid of the for loop), you could do

```
import csv

list_1 = ["Hello", "World", "Monty", "Python"]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
with open("columns.txt", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator="  ")
    writer.writerows(zip(list_1, list_2))
```

Comment: Thank you! how do I make the output of the second implementation write on the second row, I mean                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ROW1: Hello,1  World,2  Monty,3  Python,4                                                                                          ROW2: Hello,1  World,2  Monty,3  Python,4